# C++: How initialize a map that contains a list of pointers with a given key?

Tags: c++, list, dictionary, stl, key

I am doing a practice in C++ based on data structures.

My class contains an attribute like this `map<int, list <Route *>>`. My question is, what happens when I add a key to the map. Must I initialize the list or not? My wish is to have an empty file in the description of that key.

Something like this is what I thought:

```
map<int, list<Route* > >::iterator it= _mapRoutesAirline.find(IDAirline);
        if(it == _mapRoutesAirline.end())
            _mapRoutesAirline[IDAirline] = list<Route*>();
```

Comment: sorry, it is an int! would it be  `_mapRoutesAirline[IDAirline] = list<Route*>();` the correct way of coding it?

Comment: I wrote an answer. _mapRoutesAirline[IDAirline] looks for IDAirline, if it wasn't in the map, it inserts otherwise it modify the old value. I recommend using insert instead

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can simply assign to the map element (syntax assuming C++11 or above):

```cpp
 _mapRoutesAirline[IDAirline] = {};
```

Note that in many use cases you don't *have* to assign an empty list, because any attempt to access a key that isn't present in the map yet will automatically create a default constructed list for that key, which is an empty list. This means that, for example, `_mapRoutesAirline[42]` would return an empty list if you hadn't assigned anything to the `_mapRoutesAirline[42]` yet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can add an empty list to the map as value e.g.:

```
if(it == _mapRoutesAirline.end())
    _mapRoutesAirline.insert(std::make_pair(IDAirline, list<Route*>{}));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an empty list when you define a new key, no need to define the data type of the list.

```
_mapRoutesAirline[IDAirline] = {};
```

Also, you don't need to define an iterator just to find and insert element
It can be done in this way

```
if(_mapRoutesAirline.find(IDAirline) == _mapRoutesAirline.end()){
       _mapRoutesAirline[IDAirline] = {};
}
```

Comment: yes, I finally coded both of them that way. Thanks!